# CMD command in PowerShell. Quotes?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Hello I have a batch script that we use for creating appx bundles in powershell.
The script example is:

```
CMD /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64\makeappx.exe" unbundle /p C:\Temp\AppxTest.appxbundle /d C:\Temp\AppxTest
```

I would now like to use variables in the command above but from what I know `cmd /c` in PowerShell does not support variables. So I would like to have this work using native PowerShell commands.

Following PowerShell code is my attempt at getting this working. I can't seem to work out where the quotes go to make this command work in PowerShell. I've tried lots of variations of where the quotes should go but no joy.

```
Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64\makeappx.exe" "unbundle /p" "C:\Temp\AppxTest.appxbundle /d C:\Temp\AppxTest"
```

Comment: You can use environment variables in batch using `SET`

Answer (score 2):

You can call any executable from PowerShell using `&`.

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64\makeappx.exe" "unbundle /p" "C:\Temp\AppxTest.appxbundle /d C:\Temp\AppxTest"
```

This is a sample of my build script, invoking MSBuild:

```
$Msbuild = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
$Parameters= '/t:Clean',
    '/t:Rebuild',
    '/nologo',
    "/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0",
    "/p:Configuration=DEBUG",
    "/p:VersionAssembly=1.0.0"
$Target = '.\Solution.sln'
& $Msbuild $Target $Parameters
```

To use `Start-Process` you need to send an array of arguments:

```
Start-Process -FilePath ping -ArgumentList '8.8.8.8','/t'
# same as cmd /k ping 8.8.8.8 /t
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `@Parameters` so they're passed properly..

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I'm not sure what you mean by that. Most command line apps accept a `string[]` for the parameters.

Comment: Your relying on `$ofs` being equal to a space.  Splatting the parameters ensures they get to the destination properly. Do `$ofs=6` and see what I mean.  What you're doing is an implicit array concatenation

Comment: Very good point, but using splatted parameters prepends `-` to the key: `$param = @{Name='hsimah'}; & command.exe @param` sends `-Name=hsimah` to `command.exe`. This is out of the area of my PowerShell common usage - how would you handle parameters that don't need/want a leading `-`? i.e. the `usage /p` in the question, considering we aren't calling a cmdlet.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Passing array to native executable do not depend on `$ofs`.